# Is there a way to make a var of this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow piece of code:

```
case "/buy":
        $('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>').hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        break;
```

Because I have a lot of cases I want to make `.hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);` into a variable.

I tried `var addText = .hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);` but this doesn't work. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: That's called a function. What's with that selector, give that some id and reference it by id

Comment: Use the switch to determine the target ( `<p>What...` ) and fire the methods afterwards.

Comment: @user1655756 It's not a selector, it's new HTML being added to the DOM.

Comment: my bad.....-=((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't make a var of that

```
var addText = .hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
```

but you better use a function instead :-

```
var addText = function(el){
  el.hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

and use it like this:-

```
var el = $('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>');
addText(el);
```

---

or

```
addText( $('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>') )
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. I just don't know how the last piece of code works exactly. Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @Bushido Sure, addText is a function which expects a jQuery DOM element and applies the operation to it .

el is your jQuery selected element and applies rest of the operations to it. `addText( $('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>') )` So, now addText will have argument `el` having value `$('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>')` and you will perform operation to it . `el.hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);` is same as if u put the value of `el` now in  `$('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>').hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: So if I get this right then `(el)` is a function value and with `addText( $('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>') )` I am saying that I want to change `(el)` to `'<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>'` which in turn changes `el.hide()` into the specified text?

Comment: `(el)` is an argument passed to the function. so if you wanna send `el` as  `"<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>"` then you need to update function to `$(el).hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);`. Is this you are looking for ?

Comment: No the function does exactly what I need it to do, I just want to make sure I know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it into a function:

```
var hideAppendAndFade = function (element) {
    $(element).hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
};
```

Then call that function when you need to:

```
hideAppendAndFade('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>')
```

(I *guessed* that the variation would be on the selector.  Adjust for whatever else you would need to vary on, or hard-code everything if there's no variation at all between different calls of the function.)

Comment: `<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>` is not a selector, it's the HTML for a new element to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to just stack your cases.

```
case "/buy":
case "/buy2":
case "/buy3":
case "/buy4":
        $('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>').hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        break;
```

And then if you still wanted to you could create your function

```
var hideAppendAndFade = function (selector) {
    $(selector).hide().appendTo("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
};
```

and call it inside your case

```
case "/buy":
case "/buy2":
case "/buy3":
case "/buy4":
        hideAppendAndFade('<p>What do you want to buy?<br><br></p>');
        break;
```

Comment: Stacking is not an option for me but your function did do the trick. Thanks!